# Problem about SQLite's integer and int datatype

Tags: c#, sqlite, subsonic, subsonic3

I meet a problem about: **Object of type 'System.Int64' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'** when run the SubSonic.Examples.SimpleRepo project base on SQLite provider.

I fond that the data type for table Categories's column CategoryID is '**integer**', and the 'integer' in SQLite will be return as **Int64**, in the same time the CategoryID's data type in the Class Category is **int**, the above error is happened.

I checked the SubSonic's source code: \SubSonic.Core\SQLGeneration\Schema\SQLiteSchema.cs and find the following codes:

```
else if (column.IsPrimaryKey && column.DataType == DbType.Int32
    || column.IsPrimaryKey && column.DataType == DbType.Int16
    || column.IsPrimaryKey && column.DataType == DbType.Int64
    )
    sb.Append(" integer ");
```

Who can tell me the purpose for these codes?
How to solve the data type convert error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Funny I just read the sqlite3 documentation on this about an hour ago. So you're in luck :)

[See the doc yourself](http://sqlite.org/version3.html)  (Scroll to the bottom, 64-bit ROWIDs section).

Here's the excerpt:

> To minimize storage space, the 64-bit rowid is stored as a variable
> length integer. Rowids between 0 and 127 use only a single byte.
> Rowids between 0 and 16383 use just 2 bytes. Up to 2097152 uses three
> bytes. And so forth. Negative rowids are allowed but they always use
> nine bytes of storage and so their use is discouraged. When rowids are
> generated automatically by SQLite, they will always be non-negative.

### 3rd party edit

I was suprised that the `Id`-column despite being created as an int column was mapped to long as well

```
CREATE TABLE "Example" (
    "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "Foo" TEXT NULL,
    "SomeDate" DATETIME NULL
)
```

the explanation is also in the [64-bit ROWID section](https://sqlite.org/version3.html#64-bit%20ROWIDs)

> Every row of a table has a unique rowid. If the table defines a column
> with the type "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" then that column becomes an alias
> for the rowid. But with or without an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column,
> every row still has a rowid.
>
> In SQLite version 3.0, the rowid is a 64-bit signed integer.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I think I need read the SQLite document in detail.

Answer (score 8):

The PrimaryKey is set to int 64 (long) in SQLite - so you need to set yours to long as well.

Comment: It seems using long is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just stammered through a merge procedure, taking a SQL Server DataTable and merging (upsert) it with a SQLite DataTable (c# .NET win forms app). You definitely need to set your integer PK columns in the SQL Server database to BIGINT to get that to fly. Otherwise, when you call merge on the SQLite DataTable, you get a type mismatch error.